# How to change dynamically layout of child of LinearLayout on zooming

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have LinearLayout with TextView as child. On touch event over the LinearLayout, I am changing the layout of LinearLayout from one value to another value. But problem is LinearLayout enlarges but child remains same.

Xamarin.Android Project

private LinearLayout linear;

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

       linear = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.parentView);
        linear.Touch += Linear_Touch;
    }

    private void Linear_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            linear.Layout(0, 0, (500), (500));
        }
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
              android:id="@+id/parentView"
              android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
  <TextView android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Ashok kumar"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

expected result: textView also changes corresponding to the linearlayout change

Comment: Text view has fixed size of 50dp, so it can not be larger...

Comment: If I am pinch zooming the layout, will It won't change?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I modify your code about resetting LinearLayout layout, then you can use Layout_weight to get your goal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:orientation="vertical"   
android:id="@+id/parentlayout"  
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp" 
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"     
        android:text="Ashok kumar"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

 </LinearLayout>


 private void Linear_Touch(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams _params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(500, 500);
        linear.LayoutParameters = _params;
        linear.RequestLayout();

    }
```